# clientHeight returning 0 outside addEventListener function but not 0 inside

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

HTML :

```
 <div class="free-videos-content">
        <div>
            <div>Free Videos <span class="tri-down">&#9660;</span></div>
            <div class="span-childs">
                <span><i class="fa fa-book"></i> Checkout our Free Videos</span>
                <span> <i class="fa-solid fa-paperclip"></i> Assignments:1</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="free-videos-expand">
            <hr>
            <div><i class="fa-solid fa-square"></i> How to utilise Appliedaicourse</div>
            <hr>
            <div><i class="fa-solid fa-square"></i> Python for Data Science Introduction</div>
            <hr>
            <div><i class="fa-solid fa-square"></i> Python for Data Science: Data Structures</div>
            <hr>
            <div><i class="fa-solid fa-square"></i> Plotting for exploratory data analysis (EDA)</div>
            <hr>
            <div><i class="fa-solid fa-square"></i> Linear Algebra</div>
            <hr>
            <div><i class="fa-solid fa-square"></i> Probability and Statistics</div>
           
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
clickToExpandFreeVideos = document.querySelector('.free-videos-content div:first-child')
    expandedFreeVideos = document.querySelector('.free-videos-content .free-videos-expand')

    console.log(expandedFreeVideos.clientHeight);
    console.log(clickToExpandFreeVideos.clientHeight);

    clickToExpandFreeVideos.addEventListener("click", () => {
        console.log(expandedFreeVideos.clientHeight);
        console.log(clickToExpandFreeVideos.clientHeight);

    })
```

**OUTPUT IN BROWSER CONSOLE:**
0
0
403
77

as in code , 3rd and 4th output will be displayed only after clicking on clickToExpandFreeVideos

Pls explain why is this happening !

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the outer log statements are executed before the document is fully loaded. Try

```js
const clickToExpandFreeVideos = document.querySelector('.free-videos-content div:first-child')
const expandedFreeVideos = document.querySelector('.free-videos-content .free-videos-expand')

window.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
    console.log(expandedFreeVideos.clientHeight);
    console.log(clickToExpandFreeVideos.clientHeight);

});
```

This will log the values immediately after the document has fully loaded, when your divs are fully set up. Keep in mind (from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight)):

> The Element.clientHeight read-only property is zero for elements with no CSS or inline layout boxes;

So you will not get a value (other than zero) before CSS is applied.

Comment: I forgot to mention but whole JS code is already inside window's  load  event listener

Comment: Then it it probably something you do to the tags afterwards with JS. What that might be is impossible to say from the information in your question.

Comment: Look at [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) if you can work with total height of element. Also, your question does not say what you want to do with the height, but keep in mind that most things people do with element height in JS can be done more efficiently with CSS.